# Qt Creator - set architecture flag

Tags: c++, qt, kinect, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to learn how to use libfreenect with the PCL library in C++ using Qt Creator.
I'm a n00b with c++ so eventually I ran into an error compiling a sample:

```
ld: warning: in /usr/local/lib/libfreenect.dylib, file was built for i386 which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64)
make: Leaving directory `/Users/george/Documents/Qt/OKPCL'
Undefined symbols:
  "_freenect_init", referenced from:
      Freenect::Freenect::Freenect()in OKPCL.o
  "_freenect_select_subdevices", referenced from:
      Freenect::Freenect::Freenect()in OKPCL.o
  "_freenect_process_events", referenced from:
      Freenect::Freenect::operator()()in OKPCL.o
  "_freenect_shutdown", referenced from:
      Freenect::Freenect::~Freenect()in OKPCL.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [OKPCL] Error 1
The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building project OKPCL (target: Desktop)
When executing build step 'Make'
```

libfreenect is built for the i386 architecture on my machine (running osx 10.6.8).
I notice the default Make run by Qt Creator does this:

```
make: Entering directory `/Users/george/Documents/Qt/OKPCL'
g++ -headerpad_max_install_names -arch x86_64 -Xarch_x86_64 -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -o OKPCL main.o OKPCL.o   -F/Users/george/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib -L/Users/george/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/474/gcc/lib /usr/local/lib/libfreenect.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpcl_io.dylib /usr/local/lib/libpcl_common.dylib -framework QtCore
```

Is there a Qt flag I can set in the .pro file so the architecture is set to i386 instead of x86_64 ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
FOO = -arch i386
LIBS = -arch i386
LIBS += $$FOO
```

or

```
CONFIG += i386
```

EDIT

To set Qt for specific architecture you have to run you Command Prompt, enter your Qt dir and run:

```
configure -embedded i386 -no-webkit
```

After confirm you'll have to wait a while and later follow instructions. [Here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/configure-options.html) you have other flags for configure. It will configure your Qt and then you will recompile binaries. You'll be instructed how to do it after configure.

Comment: CONFIG += i386 didn't seem to change much, but the LIBS += part did. Now I've ran into more problems: It seems a lot of the libraries are built for x86_64 (PCL, QtCore, etc.). I compiled libfreenect for i386 because I have libusb also for i386. It might be simpler to compile/install libusb and libfreenect for x86_64 and carry on. Thanks the input(+1). Is there a recommended/best practice for setting arch in QT ?